# How does the half-integer spanning-tree problem contain the TSP?

Tags: reductions, minimum-spanning-tree, traveling-salesman

I am trying the understand the following statement from the book of Grotschel, Lovasz and Schrijver:

[image]

Here, $\delta(W)$ is the set of edges incident to a set of vertices $W$.

They define an optimization problem whose solution is a nonnegative real vector. If we add a constraint that all elements of the vector must be integers, then the problem is equivalent to the [minimum spanning tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), and therefore is solvable in polynomial time.
However, if the constraint says that all elements of the vector must be half-integers (that is, either an integer or an integer plus $1/2$), the problem becomes NP-complete, as it includes the symmetric [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

I do not see the connection: why does the problem with half-integer constraints contain the TSP?

Comment: What is $\delta(W)$?

Comment: @Highheath $\delta(W)$ is the set of edges with one endpoint in $W$ and the other endpoint in $V\setminus W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle (which is just a special case of TSP anyway):

Take an unweighted graph $G$ and make into a complete weighted graph $G'$ by adding a heavy edge (say, $\ell(e) = 2n$) for every $e\not\in E(G)$, and keeping $\ell(e)=1$ for $e\in E(G)$.

For any vector $\mathbf{x}$ that is a solution to the half-integer spanning tree problem, the subset of edges $F$ with $\mathbf{x}(e) > 0$ for $e\in F$ must obviously make a connected subgraph of $G$. This implies that $|F| \geq n-1$. If $|F| = n-1$, then $(V(G), F)$ is a tree and contains at least two leaves $u,v$. The edges $e_u,e_v$ incident on these leaves must have a weight of 1 in $\mathbf{x}$. Therefore the combined weight $\sum_{e\in F} \mathbf{x}(e)$ is at least $\frac{n+1}{2}$. Also, if $|F| \geq n+1$, then of course the combined weight is at least $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

On the other hand, if $|F| = n$ and every edge has a weight of $\frac{1}{2}$ in $\mathbf{x}$, then the combined weight is only $\frac{n}{2}$. This is only possible if $(V(G), F)$ is a cycle.

Therefore, $\sum_{e\in F} \mathbf{x}(e)\ell(e)$ can achieve a minimum value of $\frac{n}{2}$ if and only if $G$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: "For any vector x, the subset of edges F with ... " did you mean here: "For any vector x **that is a solution to the half-integer spanning-tree problem**"?

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=u_1,u_2,\ldots$ a solution to the STSP with cost $l$, we associate to it the vector $x_P$ such that $(x_P)_e = \frac{1}{2}\#\{i; \{u_i,u_{i+1}\}=e\}$ (each time the tour takes an edge, we add $\frac{1}{2}$ to $x_P$). It is a solution to $\frac{1}{2}$-Spanning Tree: let $W$ be a cut, the tour has to leave it and enter it at least once, so $x_P\cdot\delta(W)\geq 1$. Here $x\cdot l = \frac{1}{2}c(P)$ where $c(P)$ is the usual cost associated with the tour $P$. Hence the miminum $\frac{1}{2}$-ST solution is at least half the minimum STSP solution.

EDIT: the following is wrong, see comments

The other way around, given $x$ a solution, we construct a multigraph on $V(G)$ by putting $2x_{\{u,v\}}$ edges between each pair of vertices $u,v$. Now each vertex has degree at least $2$ (since $x\cdot \delta(\{u\})\ge 1$), so we find a tour the same way we find Eulerian tours in even degree graphs: find a cycle starting from the source, if some vertices aren't visited by the current tour $P$, we have at least two edges in $\delta(V(P))$, so we can leave, follow a path in $V(G)\setminus V(P)$ until we can go back to $P$, an obtain a bigger tour. A tour visiting all vertices uses a subset of the edges we built, and as such has weight at most $2x\cdot l$. Hence the minimum STSP solution is at most twice the miminum $\frac{1}{2}$-ST solution.

It follows the problems are equivalent.

Comment: In the Eulerian path, isn't it possible that the same vertex is visited more than once? If so, then it is not a solution to STSP.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about this condition, and there are some graphs (e.g. 2 cycles with one identified vertex) which have 1/2-spanning trees and no TSP tour. Maybe we have to prove that if there is a TSP tour, any solution to 1/2-ST can be made into a tour?

Comment: Maybe the *minimum* 1/2-ST is always a TSP tour?